# Integrability of dirichlet function in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $d: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the Dirichlet function as follows:

$$d(x) =
\begin{cases} 
      1, & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
      0, & x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}.$$

Consider, then, the set $$S :=o(d) = \{(a,b) \in [0,1]^2 : 0 \leq b \leq d(a)\},$$ the set of all the points between the dirichlet function and the x axis.

Finally, let: $ f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be defined as:
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases} 
      1, & (x,y) \in S \\
      0, & (x,y) \notin S
\end{cases}.$$

Is this function Riemann integrable?
In other words, does the volume of o(f) exist? Equivalently, does $\partial S$ have null Jordan measure?

I can see that $ \partial S = [0,1]^2$, but for me it is ambiguous whether the Jordan measure of $\partial S$ is null. If we consider 3 dimensional intervals containing the boundary of S, then it is clear that we can make the 3 dimensional volume as small as we please by making the "thickness of the slab" as small as we please. However, if we consider the same set $[0,1]^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it certainly doesn't have null Jordan measure, for the volume of a 2 dimensional interval containing it is certainly at least 1.
I can't resolve this conflict...

Comment: Do you mean $\{(a,b) \in [0,1]^2 : 0 \leq b \leq d(a)\}$?

Comment: This function is not Riemann integrable. The argument to show this is the same as the argument to show that Dirichlet's function is not integrable.

Comment: But what is the mistake with the argument I showed above? I can't decide about the Jordan measure of $\partial S$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your "for" argument is that the $3$-dimensional Jordan content of $S$ is zero because $S \subset [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \times (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$.

But the relevant criterion is whether the *$2$-dimensional* Jordan content of $S$ is zero, and the Jordan content of $S$ is unity.

Perhaps it helps to observe that "the one-variable Dirichlet function regarded as a function of two variables", namely,
$$
f(x, y)
  = \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if $y = 0$ and $x$ is rational,} \\
  0 & \text{otherwise,}
  \end{cases}
$$
*is* Riemann integrable over the square, because the discontinuity set $(\mathbf{Q} \cap [0, 1]) \times \{0\}$ has ($2$-dimensional) Jordan content zero.

Comment: We have to consider the 2-dimensional Jordan content of S due to the fact that S is defined in two dimensions, am I right? Is it always necessary to evaluate the content of a set in the same space as it is defined for considerations of integrability?

For example, in the $f$ function you have just presented, the discontinuity set has null 2 dimensional Jordan measure but not null 1D Jordan measure, leading to the same confusion as before by the way I was thinking. This conflict is resolved by taking the 2D jordan measure of the discontinuity set because it "lives" in 2 dimensions, right?

Comment: @RuiCarneiro: Yes, exactly. :) In other words, one should speak of a function being "Riemann integrable on $D \subset \mathbf{R}^{n}$" rather than simply being "integrable" (though in practice the domain and its dimension are implicit).